# tsunami Windows 10 curl JAVA_HOME environment variable error

Tags: java, windows, bash, github, curl

I am setting up tsunami on Windows 10. I am following the tutorial (https://github.com/google/tsunami-security-scanner). When I run the bash command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

When I run echo %JAVA_HOME%, I get

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_351
```

What possible explanation could there be for this?

The role of the `bash -c "$(curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/tsunami-security-scanner/master/quick_start.sh)"` command is described at https://github.com/google/tsunami-security-scanner.

Comment: try `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your WSL terminal please. Note that `%JAVA_HOME%` implies MS Windows `.bat` files, etc. In any case, this Q would be more appropriate on [su]. Good luck.

Comment: I am using the command prompt, not WSL.

Comment: Windows `bash.exe` automatically runs in (aka switches to) WSL, so **you ARE using WSL** -- and WSL doesn't use most env vars from Windows. WSL does set its $PATH partly from the Windows %PATH% converted to WSL name format and Unix separators, so if your Windows PATH finds your java then your WSL PATH should also. Note Oracle installers for the last several years don't put the actual location `\Program Files [(x86)]\Java\<version>` in your (Windows) PATH, they use a stub in `\Program Files [(x86)]\Common Files\Oracle` or `\ProgramData\Oracle`. They also kill old versions, and 351 is not head.

Comment: All I get back from echo $JAVA_HOME is $JAVA_HOME

Comment: try `bash -c "$(export JAVA_HOME="yourPath_to_JAVA_HOME" ; curl -sfL https://...../quick_start.sh)`. Good luck.